# POWERBI: take while table when there is no available relation

Tags: powerbi

I have a slight issue with my tables in POWERBI. In short, I have a missing link in one of my relations. As a result, instead of returning NOTHING which is logical and actually what I would like, it returns EVERYTHING.

A bit more details, I have the multiple tables with relations between them. The problem is that I have a few task_group pointing toward shipments that do not exist. In my visualization, I am trying to access data (a count of the number of Packages linked to a shipment) that is linked to a shipment. The logical thing for me would be that "If there is no shipment fitting the number that is given in the shipment table, then you cannot count the number of packages linked to that shipment".
But PowerBI beg to differ. His idea is "If I cannot find a shipment to link to package, i'm going to take every single package regardless of shipment". As a result, a group of task that do not have any package end up showing as having all the packages instead. How can I tell powerbi to return nothing if he doesn't find anything instead of returning everything?

[Image of my relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TU6l.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think Power BI behaves slightly unintuitively where there are nulls on one side of a join.

Have you tried filtering to only include where shipment_id is not blank?

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is you having NULLs in one side of the relationship, the best way to tackle this would be to replace the NULLs with something else. Now, you can do it in two ways:

1. Edit the Shipment number NULLs to something else in the Power query while importing (Some number which is not likely to be an actual shipment, maybe 0)
2. Create a calculated field in DAX replacing the blanks/NULLs and use that in the relationship instead

But I think you may have NULLs in both the sides of the relationship. That is the only explanation I can think of, why Power BI is behaving this way. Either way, the above solutions should fix it.

Comment: It's not that there is null. it's rather that it's pointing to something that doesn't exist. Basically, due to how the previous devs set-up the DB a picking task group get assigned a shipment BOL then the shipment is created for billing. problem is that, when we didn't send a bill (because we sent free samples) it didn't generate the shipment. There is a BOL because we sent something, but because it didn't got through some part of the process, it didn't create the shipment. thus technically, it isn't that there is no link (PIcking.task_group.shipment isn't null, but it point to non existence)